# Count the number of opened tabs in Terminal

Tags: linux, shell

How can I get the number of opened tabs in Terminal via shell?
I know how to get the number of opened Terminals but I don't know how to get the number of opened tabs for each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 ps --ppid $(pgrep gnome-terminal) | grep -c bash
```